# Write out the matched lines in python

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to print out the line of the matched pattern and write out the matched lines.

The number of the matched line works fine, however, neither did Python write the content in the new file, nor did it raise an error message.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import re
outputLineNumbers = open('OutputLineNumbers', 'w')
outputLine = open('OutputLine', 'w')
inputFile = open('z.vcf','r')
matchLines = inputFile.readlines()    


total = 0
for i in range(len(matchLines)):
    line = matchLines[i]
#print out the matched line number    
    if re.match('(\w+)\|(\d+)\|(\w+)\|AGTA(\d+)\.(\d)\|\s(0+\d+)\s\.\s(\w)\s(\w),(\w)', line):
        total += 1
        outputLineNumbers.write( str(i+1) + "\n" )
#WRITE out the matched line
    if line == ('(\w+)\|(\d+)\|(\w+)\|AGTA(\d+)\.(\d)\|\s(0+\d+)\s\.\s(\w)\s(\w),(\w)'):
        outputLine.write( line + "\n" )
print "total polyploid marker is : ", total


outputLineNumbers.close()
inputFile.close()
outputLine.close()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You tried to test if the line is equal to the pattern:

```
if line == ('(\w+)\|(\d+)\|(\w+)\|AGTA(\d+)\.(\d)\|\s(0+\d+)\s\.\s(\w)\s(\w),(\w)'):
```

String equality does not magically invoke the regular expression engine when the string appears to contain a pattern, however.

Remove the `if line ==` test and just write out the matched line as part of the preceding `if` block:

```
if re.match('(\w+)\|(\d+)\|(\w+)\|AGTA(\d+)\.(\d)\|\s(0+\d+)\s\.\s(\w)\s(\w),(\w)', line):
    total += 1
    outputLineNumbers.write( str(i+1) + "\n" )
    #WRITE out the matched line
    outputLine.write( line + "\n" )
```

Note that you can just loop over `matchLines` *directly*; use the [`enumerate()` function](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#enumerate) to produce a running index here instead:

```
for i, line in enumerate(matchLines, 1):
    if re.match('(\w+)\|(\d+)\|(\w+)\|AGTA(\d+)\.(\d)\|\s(0+\d+)\s\.\s(\w)\s(\w),(\w)', line):
        total += 1
        outputLineNumbers.write("{}\n".format(i))
```

where `i` starts at 1, so there is no need to add 1 later on either.

Comment: @TimPietzcker: I recommend the [right firearm for the job](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dvorak_Simplified_Keyboard).. :-)

Comment: I think my wife would kill me if I switched our QWERTZ keyboard to Dvorak. So, are you really that much faster? How long did it take to get used to it?

Comment: I also wouldn't loop over the `matchLines` that way. It's not even remotely pythonic. Try `for i, line in enumerate(matchLines)`

Comment: @TimPietzcker: It took me about 2 weeks to learn. I switch keyboards in software, a quick CMD-space and others can use the QWERTY keyboard (as labelled). But my wife doesn't want me to type for prolonged periods of time nearby her, she claims the rhythm of the Dvorak patterns drive her up the wall....

Comment: @MartijnPieters: normally not, but he uses the index of the loop a few lines below

Comment: thank you, sorry just started python, borrowed lines from here and there, would you mind explaining the differences?

Comment: @user2489612: You already tested if the  line matched, you didn't need to test again. Your test didn't work, because when you test strings for equality, they need to have the exact same contents; `'123' == '123'` will be true, but `'123' == '\d+'` is not going to be equal, even though the second string might look like a regular expression.

Comment: @user2489612: the rest of my answer is just general advice with explanation; anything specific you don't understand?

Comment: no, i just wanted to understand the differences 'for i, line in enumerate(matchLines)' and 'for i, line in enumerate(matchLines)', is it a stylish thing or something more superior down the line of learning python?

Comment: @user2489612 `matchLines` is a python list object. As such, it is possible to iterate over its elements simply using an `for x in list` statement. No worries about index out of range or similar errors. That way, though, you miss the index of the current element in your loop. If you need it, you can use the builtin `enumerate` function, that will return two values: the current index and the current element of the list. That's a pretty rough explanation, but you have plenty to read at http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#enumerate

Comment: ahhh, this is really helpful, if enumerate can return both index and content of the line, i do not even need "line = matchLines[i] ", and "outputLine1.write( line + "\n" )" can be written as "outputLine1.write( matchLines + "\n" )" ?

Comment: @user2489612: the `for` loop now binds `i` *and* `line` for you, from each tuple returned by `enumerate()`. You'd still use `outputLine1.write(line + '\n')`; you want to write the individual line, not the whole list.

Comment: sorry my bad, i was meant to say outputLine1.write( line + "\n" ) can just write the output without pre index it, thanks a ton.